# Runtime error on Angular app when AoT is enabled

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I recently updated my app's Angular version from 2.4 to 5.1.2, following the guidelines in this tool: https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/. I'm also using angular-cli 1.6.3

Now, after updating, everything works in dev mode when running `ng serve`. Also `ng build` (with or without `--aot` flag) runs without errors. However, `ng serve --aot` or `ng serve --prod` produces a runtime error:

[image: ng serve --aot runtime error]

I have found it very difficult to debug this problem, because the stack trace doesn't point to any file written by me. Could it perhaps be a bootstrapping problem?

At this point I'm not looking for complete solutions to the issue, but suggestions as to where I could start looking.

I have tried so far:

- Searching for similar issues, this could be related: [Error when loading a Angular app with AOT build on Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884127/error-when-loading-a-angular-app-with-aot-build-on-amazon-s3)
- Checked that my bootstrapping configuration in `main.ts` matches some examples
- Updated node from 9.1.0 to 9.3.0 (Suggested by Vincent)
- Created a new angular-cli project and copied the polyfills.ts file from the new project to my existing one

Comment: Hi ! Maybe just updating node to new version can solve the problem ;) I know it's not a real solution but i think i faced this problem and solved it like that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Hi again ^^ searching deeper in my commits i noticed that i updated node but what fixed the problem was downgrading angular cli from 1.5.2 to 1.5.0 and it worked, later i updated to 1.6.x and it still working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never figured out what was the actual problem, but it was definitely related to animations. The error disappeared when I completely disabled animations for the app, which is not ideal but works as a temporary fix until I have more time to re-write any modules and/or components that used to use animations.

Answer (score 0):

My angular packages, from npm, did not have matching version numbers. I was able to use both `ng serve --aot` and `ng serve --prod` after aligning all my library versions!

This would make sense if the runtime was able to handle internal compatibilities softly before AOT was a thing. Now that we have AOT, performance is key so the runtimes fail safes have been stripped out.

Animations all work just fine as well.